# determining if the user is logged in

Tags: users

I am new to wordpress, and trying to get my head around the idea of sessions and all. I read in a lot of places that session concept is not used in wordpress. Anyway, I downloaded the my-login-theme plugin. My question is, when a user navigates to some secured area, I want to check if that user is logged in or not. Once I check that, I want to get user details like email, and full name. Is this possible in wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `is_user_logged_in()` conditional tag ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)) to determine if the current user is logged in.

Use the `get_userdata()` function ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)) to return user data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_user_logged_in()` to see if the user is logged in. You can use `get_userdata()` to get the logged in users info.

If you want to restrict access to pages, have you looked at using the plugin `Members` You can enable shortcodes and template tags to control restricted content to Roles.

Comment: I'm still learning SE etiquette, so perhaps it's normal; but: why post almost exactly the same answer I did?

Comment: If you look at the timestamps we both posted near the same time. So when I was typing my reply there wasn't any answers. You posted just ahead of me. Normally I would remove my answer but because I offer some other help I have left it up.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, then!