# Must Log In to Visit Site

Tags: login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [determining if the user is logged in](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14834/determining-if-the-user-is-logged-in)

Please check my site http://247ebookstore.com/sg3/monestatic-igues/ still working on it. If you check the given page you'll see "Visit Website" button there. I want that User must Logged In to view the website link. I don't know much coding so please anyone kindly tell me the code and place where to put it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try **[searching the site for related answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is_user_logged_in)** before posting?

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Private Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-only/) a shot - but it's best for you to do your own research on the [Plugin Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) to find the plugin that suites your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap any content with:

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>

Only for logged in users

<?php else: ?>

You need to login

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I couldn't find that code. Could you please help me? Any logged in user can submit the listing so I don't know how this theme working in creating listing. Where to put this code?

Comment: You need to add that code to the template that is creating the "View Website button". Wrap the `if( is_user_logged_in() )` code around that button.

Comment: Thanks developdaly, You made my day. I found the place its "_single.php" I've edited it and wrapped the codes as you instructed and it worked! http://247ebookstore.com/sg5/directorypress/

Comment: Now what I want is, if user is paid member(Gold Member on my site) and if user has visited the site in 24 hours and if the sweepstakes is of category "one entry/day" then it shows "You have already entered for today" and if it is one time entry then it shows "Already Entered" so my Gold members don't get disqualified and this would be the main feature for members. If you can tell me code then I would be thankful.

Comment: You should accept this answer as complete and open a new question ... this one was closed, so you'll get better responses with a new Q.